# This is what I'm trying to write. What is the best way to write it in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
models = Model.joins("inner join manufs_models on manufs_models.manuf_id = 3 or manufs_models.manuf_id = 5 or manufs_models.manuf_id = 9 or manufs_models.manuf_id = 10")
```

How can I write this concisely?

Comment: could you clarify: `write this concisely?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more concise:

```
models = Model.joins("inner join manufs_models on manufs_models.manuf_id IN (3,5,9,10)")
```